# How to secure querystring/POST details to a third party

Tags: redirect, iframe, asp.net-mvc-4, proxy

I'm basically looking at a security problem between a parent page and an iframe with links to a third party.

I want to send a POST or a GET (doesn't matter which as I can control the other side) to the third party, but not expose any details within it (say a SID or a user token) and have it's HTML content (JS/HTML/Images) loaded into the iframe.

I've looked at server-side redirects, creating a proxy using webclinet/webresponse and am curious to whether there is a good way to do it.

Has anyone ever done this before, or think that the secrity is not possible? Hell, even if I'm barking up the wrong tree on how to solve this.

If anybody has any examples on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Jamie

[Edit] Was thinking I might need to add some more details.

Say I have a parent page: https://mycompany.com/ShowThirdParty.

This has an iframe in it at the moment which will have the content of another component (also owned by me, or another team more specifically)

Basically I'd like to send some credentials to content in the iframe in such a way that the external pages can't read it, the iframe is put into a modal (I've done that) and the iframe has the restricted content with the auhtentication almost seamless and invisible.

I currently have it working as a GET url generated dynamically via JS and then passed into the iframe src parameter, obviously that isn't secure.

I kind of want some kind of server side redirect across a full url, but I don't even think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using AJAX and load a PHP script (with any parameters to the script encoded/encrypted) to query the 3rd party page and load the response into the iframe. Not really sure how your code is setup but there should be a way.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by POST Method (submit the data to iFrame using POST) as it is HTTPS so the data you send to iFrame is encryped.

Comment: But won't the values by readable from within the page? I.e using Chromium or Firebug.